# Elasticsearch snapshot for a cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-snapshot

I have a Elasticsearch cluster running with three nodes.
and have created a snapshot repository for the cluster, and trying to create a snapshot manually using,

> 10.0.0.120:9200/_snapshot/$REPO_NAME/$SNAPSHOT_NAME

But I am not sure if I have to create snapshot from all nodes or from any one node?
And if i have to make snapshot call from all nodes seperately, should the name of snapshot be same?

Also is there a way to verify if the snapshot is fine without restoring it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html) “A snapshot is a backup of a running Elasticsearch cluster.”

So all nodes will be in, and you don’t need to make separate snapshots.

Comment: yes, this is absolutely correct! :)

Comment: So, calling the create snapshot api from any one node would create snapshot for complete cluster?

Comment: @sjsj15 yes. You are not calling one node- you are operating with cluster REST API.